# How to add custom field value in Odoo Invoice sequence in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I was trying to add custom field into Invoice number sequence.

So the field I added was a many2one field or selection field whose value needs to be appended to the Invoice sequence.

The field is in account.invoice class

```py
seq_pat = fields.Many2one('account.sequence.new','Sequence Pattern')
```

Other way I was trying is by overriding ir.sequence class method which creates the legends in sequences.

```py
class ir_sequence(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'ir.sequence'

    def _interpolation_dict_context(self, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        test1 = self.pool.get('account.invoice').browse()
        test = test1.seq_pat.name
        t = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(context.get('tz') or 'UTC'))
        sequences = {
            'year': '%Y', 'month': '%m', 'day': '%d', 'y': '%y', 'doy': '%j', 'woy': '%W',
            'weekday': '%w', 'h24': '%H', 'h12': '%I', 'min': '%M', 'sec': '%S',
            'pattern': '%P'
        }
        return {key: t.strftime(sequence) for key, sequence in sequences.iteritems()}
```

which succeeded in making it to the legends section of Odoo. 
[image: Legends]

But I am stuck with how to get my field recognised by ir.sequence.

Anyone with any other idea to achieve this would be really helpful.